# Add folder prefix from LastWriteTime of content files

Tags: file, powershell, directory, rename

I got a folder with about 42 000 .jpg and video files, which are sorted by year/month in different subfolders. The structure looks like:

```
├─2015
│ ├─01 - january
│ │ ├─holiday
│ │ └─biking
│ └─02 - february
│   ├─skiing
│   └─etc
└─2016
  └─01 - january
```

I now wanted to add to all subfolders (eg. holiday), a prefix of the lastwritetime of the containing .jpg files. For a clearer explanition:

File holiday has the lastwritetime 2015-01-01
The "holiday" folder would then be renamed to "2015-01-01 - holiday".

I already googled/searched/even tried to adjust some code snippets I found but without any sucess. Could maybe somebody help me out here?

EDIT:

Sorry for the unreadable code in my comment.  Here once again:

```
$dir = Get-Childitem 'C:\temp\2011' -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName

$file = Get-Childitem -Path $dir -filter '*.jpg' 

Rename-Item -Path $dir.FullName -NewName ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1}' -f $file.LastWriteTime, $dir.Name)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing a folder with its last write date is fairly trivial. Basically it goes like this:

```
Get-Item 'C:\some\folder' |
  Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1}' -f $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Name }
```

`Rename-Item` reads the objects to rename from the pipeline and the scriptblock passed to the `-NewName` parameter constructs the new name from the object's name and last write time (see [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) for further information on the format operator).

The approach for renaming a folder to the last write time of a file is similar:

```
$dir  = Get-Item 'C:\some\folder'
$file = Get-Item 'C:\path\to\your.jpg'
Rename-Item -Path $dir.FullName -NewName ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1}' -f $file.LastWriteTime, $dir.Name)
```

---

**Edit:** Your updated code gets you one list of directories plus one list of files. That's not going to work for what you want. You need to get a list of directories, and then get a list of files for each directory:

```
Get-Childitem 'C:\temp\2011' -Recurse | Where-Object {
  $_.PSIsContainer
} | ForEach-Object {
  $dir = $_
  $files_in_dir = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName -Filter '*.jpg'
}
```

Determine the file by which you want to rename the folder from that list, then rename the folder:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
  ...
  $file = $files_in_dir | ...
  Rename-Item -Path $dir.FullName -NewName (...)
}
```

Comment: Again thanks for your fast reponse Angsar. I tried it out and I am getting the following error (its german, but maybe you can interpret the error?): 
PS J:\> C:\temp\1\Unbenannt2.ps1
Rename-Item : Der Parameter "NewName" kann nicht ausgewertet werden, da dessen Argument als Skriptblock angegeben wurde und keine Eingabe vorhanden ist. Ein Skriptblock kann nicht ohne Eingabe ausgewertet werden.

Comment: Bei C:\temp\1\Unbenannt2.ps1:3 Zeichen:41
+ Rename-Item -Path $dir.FullName -NewName <<<<  { '{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1}' -f $file.LastWriteTime, $file.Name }
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: My bad. It must be a subexpression (parentheses) in the second example, not a scriptblock (curly brackets).

Comment: I want to go threw the whole folder structure, renaming all files automaticaly (without the obligation to edit the file & folder path). Do you know where my "thinkerror" is? What am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think all Ansgar's answer is missing is a for-each loop, so you can rename all the directories. Also, if you have multiple files per directory, you need to decide which of the files' last write time should be used (I'm using latest below)

```
$dir = get-item 'C:\temp\2011' -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } 
$dir |  % {  $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName | Sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -first 1; 
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1}' -f $file.LastWriteTime, $_.Name) }
```